# Angular blocking (synchronize) http call

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, synchronous

I have an Angular app which renews the jwt every 2 mins. There is a potential issue is, while the jwt is renewing, user may do some action will fire another http call go with the old jwt.

How can I ensure the renewjwt() is finished before another potential http calls fire?

My initial idea is toggling a global flag before renewjwt() call and in the callback function that when it is done.

Is there a good way to accomplish this with native Angular or rxjs?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `delayWhen` operator which will delay emitted values base on another observable.

for that you can create observable like following :

```
function renewTokenIfNeeded$(): Observable<void> {
  console.log('Renew token start');
  /**
   * Here you should have have :
   * If current token is valid, 
   * ---- then return of(number),
   * else
   * ---- then return this.http.post([...])
   */
  // for demonstration prupose i always renew the token.
  return of(null).pipe(delay(
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1  
  ), tap(() => console.log('renew token stop')));

}

/**
 * Each 100 ms i trigger new dummy http request. By exhaustMap i will ignore all future "interval" emission until my dummy http request is complete stream.
 */
const renewTokensTimer$ = interval(100).pipe(exhaustMap(() => renewTokenIfNeeded$()));
```

data stream will looks like :

```
|...|...|...|................|...|...|...|
```

1/ Like this i have stream which will emit new number each 100ms until you consider your current as dirty.

2/ Then it will perform the http request to fetch the new one.

3/ The interval source observable will not emit new value until you exhaust the http request.

then you can simply use it like following :

```
of(null) // Create dummy observable.
    .pipe(delayWhen(() => renewTokenIfNeeded$())) // Delay it if token have to be renew.
    .pipe(mergeMap(() => myRegularHttpRequest$)) // perform my http request, i am 100% here i have fresh JWT
    .subscribe(console.log) // You can safely consume the API answer.
```

[live poc](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-yk4cp2?devtoolsheight=60)

Answer (score 0):

I do that through a `Promise` storing the pending Promise for renewal when it has been sent and the reply has not yet been received.

The `getToken` function of the auth service returns a `Promise`:

```js
if (this.promiseRefreshToken) {
  /* Path 1 */
  this.log.debug('Refresh token is already pending, waiting for the answer to be received.');
  return this.promiseRefreshToken;
} else {
  /* Path 2 */
  if /* no need to renew */
    return Promise.resolve(token);
  else
    return getRefreshToken();
}
```

The `refreshToken` function actually has the responsibility for correctly setting `promiseRefreshToken` (member variable for the service):

```js
return this.promiseRefreshToken = this.api_query./* API QUERY FOR TOKEN */
  .then(api_resp => {
    this.promiseRefreshToken = null;
    return /* the token */;
  })
  .catch(api_error => {
    this.promiseRefreshToken = null;
    return Promise.reject('Error...');
  });
```

When the reply actually comes in, don't forget to revert the `Promise` to null for subsequent calls to use the usual logic (Path 2 above).

That way, it is guaranteed that you never have two concurrent requests for a token refresh.